# Unable to build go program in multistage build with undefined error in Docker

Tags: docker, go

I am trying to learn go and I have build my first go program on something simple as.

```bash
❯ tree .
.
├── README.md
├── convert.go
├── dockerfile
├── go.mod
├── go.sum
├── main.go
├── pageindices.go
├── pageindices_test.go
├── pdf2png.go
└── pdf2png_test.go
```

what my docker file looks like the following

```
ARG GOLANG_IMAGE_TAG="1.20.6-alpine"
FROM golang:${GOLANG_IMAGE_TAG} as base

ARG PDF2IMG_VERSION=dev

# So using 8.14.2 for now
ARG VIPS_VERSION="8.14.2"

RUN apk update && apk add --no-cache \
     automake build-base pkgconfig glib-dev expat-dev gobject-introspection \
     libjpeg-turbo-dev libpng-dev libwebp-dev giflib-dev librsvg-dev libexif-dev lcms2-dev
# Exit 0 added because warnings tend to exit the build at a non-zero status
RUN cd /root \
    && mkdir vips \
    && wget -q0- "https://github.com/libvips/libvips/releases/download/v${VIPS_VERSION}/vips-${VIPS_VERSION}.tar.gz" | tar -xzf - -C vips --strip-components=1 \
    && cd vips \
    && CFLAGS="-g -O3" CXXFLAGS="-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0 -g -O3" ./configure \
        --disable-debug \
        --disable-dependency-tracking \
        --disable-introspection \
        --disable-static \
        --enable-gtk-doc-html=no \
        --enable-gtk-doc=no \
        --enable-pyvips8=no && \
    make && make install-strip && ldconfig; exit 0
RUN export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/vips/lib
RUN apk del automake build-base

# create a working directory inside the image
WORKDIR /go/src/github.com/felixgao/pdf2img
# Cache go modules
ENV GO111MODULE=on

# Copy go mod and sum files
COPY go.mod go.sum ./

# Download all dependencies. Dependencies will be cached if the go.mod and go.sum files are not changed
RUN go mod download


# copy directry files i.e all files ending with .go 
COPY *.go .

# Build the Go app with ldflags
RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux go build -a \
    -ldflags="-s -w -h -X main.Version=${PDF2IMG_VERSION}" \
    -o pdf2png


# build target image
FROM golang:${GOLANG_IMAGE_TAG} as prod
WORKDIR /app/
RUN apk --update add --no-cache \
    fftw glib expat libjpeg-turbo libpng \
    libwebp giflib librsvg libgsf libexif lcms2
WORKDIR /root/
COPY --from=base /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt /etc/ssl/certs/
COPY --from=base /root/libs/* /root/libs/
COPY --from=base /usr/local/lib/* /usr/local/lib/
COPY --from=base /go/src/github.com/felixgao/pdf2img/pdf2png .


#tell docker what port to expose
EXPOSE 8080

# Run the binary program produced by `go install`
CMD ["./pdf2png"]
```

my go.mod file looks like

```golang
module github.com/felixgao/pdf_to_png

go 1.20

require github.com/davidbyttow/govips/v2 v2.13.0

require (
    golang.org/x/image v0.9.0 // indirect
    golang.org/x/net v0.12.0 // indirect
    golang.org/x/text v0.11.0 // indirect
)
```

When I built it, it kept telling me the required package is not there.  I thought go mod download would pull that down for me. Am I missing something?

```bash
=> CACHED [base  6/10] WORKDIR /go/src/github.com/felixgao/pdf2img                    0.0s
 => CACHED [base  7/10] COPY go.mod go.sum ./                                          0.0s
 => [base  8/10] RUN go mod download                                                   6.0s
 => [base  9/10] COPY *.go .                                                           0.0s
 => ERROR [base 10/10] RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux go build -a     -ldflags="-s -w -  4.5s
------
 > [base 10/10] RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux go build -a     -ldflags="-s -w -h -X main.Version=dev"     -o pdf2png:
#18 4.394 # github.com/felixgao/pdf_to_png
#18 4.394 ./pdf2png.go:29:29: undefined: vips.ImageType
#18 4.394 ./pdf2png.go:30:7: undefined: vips.ImageTypeJPEG
#18 4.394 ./pdf2png.go:31:7: undefined: vips.ImageTypePNG
#18 4.394 ./pdf2png.go:32:7: undefined: vips.ImageTypeTIFF
#18 4.394 ./pdf2png.go:35:41: undefined: vips.ImageType
#18 4.394 ./pdf2png.go:36:15: undefined: vips.ImageTypeJPEG
#18 4.394 ./pdf2png.go:37:15: undefined: vips.ImageTypePNG
#18 4.394 ./pdf2png.go:38:15: undefined: vips.ImageTypeTIFF
#18 4.394 ./pdf2png.go:41:25: undefined: vips.ImageRef
#18 4.394 ./pdf2png.go:41:86: undefined: vips.ImageMetadata
#18 4.394 ./pdf2png.go:41:86: too many errors
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux go build -a     -ldflags="-s -w -h -X main.Version=${PDF2IMG_VERSION}"     -o pdf2png]: exit code: 1pdf2png]: exit code: 1
```

When run the build command locally, it works fine.

```bash
❯ go build -a -ldflags="-s -w -h -X main.Version=dev" -o pdf2png && echo $?
0
❯ ls -al pdf2png
-rwxr-xr-x  1 ggao  staff  6334226 Jul 18 17:52 pdf2png
```

I would expect the go mod download will pull down the necessary packages and allows the build to pass as it is passing in my local without using docker.

Answer (score 3):

I believe the issue is `go mod tidy`. Your Dockerfile runs this command before any Go source files have been copied to the build container. So Go aggressively tidies go.mod by removing *all* dependencies.

In this case I think you can just remove the `go mod tidy`. Especially since this isn't the final build stage in the Dockerfile.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I have tried to remove the go mod tidy and now facing the undefined symbol problem. I will update my original post to reflect that.

Comment: @FelixGao At this point I think the question has moved from Golang to libvips. There are a couple of errors earlier in the Dockerfile where libvips is compiled and installed. So vips is not actually available in the Docker container. But the errors were ignored due to the 'exit 0' statement at the end of that long RUN clause.

Comment: @FelixGao I tried looking into it further to diagnose the libvips error. I can tell you that you probably want to downgrade to 8.13.3 to make the build work. (The vips 8.14 source is published using .tar.xz files, not .tar.gz -- and they also changed their build system to something called meson.)

Comment: @FelixGao At this point I'm out of my depth because I don't know what libvips actually is... To further debug, I recommend: removing the 'exit 0' from the build step (so errors will stop the Docker build), and adding `set -x` to your RUN statements. –– Also one more note: the line `RUN export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/vips/lib` doesn't do anything. Each RUN statement spawns a new shell, so the setting won't be persisted. You'll have to set that environment variable every time you need it.